# "The file seems to be corrupted" (Apple Music)

Tags: error, apple-music

I cannot for the life of me seem to redownload two particular tracks. One of them is "Wake Up" by Arcade Fire.

No matter how many times I try and download it - iTunes will always complain that the file is corrupted.

I can't even remove it from my library, the "Delete Song" dialog seems to have no effect whatsoever.

[image]

How should I go about solving this?

Comment: Perhaps any download is deliberately corrupted as it is not properly available...

Comment: @SolarMike it works fine on my iPhone (redownloading as well).